# Is there a way to detect text-only zooming in all major browsers?

Tags: zooming, browser-detection

I've done some research and found numerous posts including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) but they are all old and the answer on that page links to a library that says it no longer works in Firefox or Chrome.

Is there a current, reliable way to detect zooming and text-only zooming in browsers? How can it be handled?

Comment: It may no longer be necessary depending on your use case.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you wanting to resize something via javascript when the user zooms text?

Comment: @JECarterII preferably with CSS only, but I understand Javascript will likely be required. I am able to do it now by running an interval (`setInterval( checkSomeDivsWidth, 500 )`) but this means code needs to be running all the time.

Comment: Post up the section of javascript you're running in that interval.  I suspect there may be a pure CSS option for you.

Answer (score -3):

script for zoom

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/swfZoomDetection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  swfZoomDetection.init({
 'onZoomChange': function(obj){ alert(obj.scale) },
 'getInitIfOne': true,
 'initCallOnly': false,
 'frameRate': 25
  });
</script>
```

text to be zoomed

```
  <body onLoad="loadFunction()">
  function loadFunction(){
     swfZoomDetection.init({ .... });
  }
 </body>
```

Comment: Please say where you got the code from and link to the actual files needed to be included. In this case: http://blog.sebastian-martens.de/2009/12/how-to-detect-the-browser-zoom-level-change-browser-zoo/